# Testing bottle api using curl

Tags: ubuntu, curl, bottle

I was trying to inspect a plain text response from an api I built, by doing something like:
`curl 127.0.0.1/myapi/test` from linux shell

However for some reason result came back truncated, also when trying to do something like `curl 127.0.0.1/myapi/test > response_log.txt` didn't work.

Do we have any limitation on response got from curl and if so how can I unlimit it?

Comment: Here's an alternative, [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie). `pip install httpie`, then in terminal `http :<port>` for a local server.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limitation in curl.

Try `curl -v 127.0.0.1/myapi/test > resp.txt` and check the value of the `Content-Length` header. If it matches the size of `resp.txt`, then it's the server that is truncating the response.

If `Content-length` is greater than the size of `resp.txt`, then perhaps your connection is getting closed prematurely; e.g. a timeout. Is it a long-running request?